# Write a function that determines the maximum number of consecutive BA, CA character pairs per line

Tags: python, string, methods

My respects, colleagues.
I need to write a function that determines the maximum number of consecutive BA, CA character pairs per line.

```
print(f("BABABA125"))  # -> 3
print(f("234CA4BACA"))  # -> 2
print(f("BABACABACA56"))  # -> 5
print(f("1BABA24CA"))  # -> 2
```

Actually, I've written a function, but, to my mind, it's not very good.

```
def f(s: str) -> int:

    res = 0

    if not s:
        return res

    cur = 0
    i = len(s) - 1

    while i >= 0:
        if s[i] == "A" and (s[i-1] == "B" or s[i-1] == "C"):
            cur += 1
            i -= 2
        else:
            if cur > res:
                res = cur
                cur = 0
            i -= 1
    else:
        if cur > res:
            res = cur

    return res
```

***In addition, I'm not allowed to use libraries and regular expressions (only string and list methods)***. Could you please help me or rate my code in this context. I'll be very grateful.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative implementation without any imports. Do note however that it's quite slow compared to your C-style implementation.

The idea is simple: Transform the input string into a string consisting of only two types of characters `c1` and `c2`, with `c1` representing `CA` or `BA`, and `c2` representing anything else. Then find the longest substring of consecutive `c1`s.

The implementation is as follows:

1. Pick a char that is guaranteed not to appear in the input string; here we use `+` as an example. Then pick a char different from the previous one; here we use `-`.
2. Replace each occurrence of `CA` and `BA` with a `+`.
3. Replace everything else in the string (that is not a `+`) with a `-` (this is why `+` cannot be present in the original input string). Now we have a string consisting purely of `+`s and `-`s.
4. Split the string with `-` as delimiter, and map each resulting substring to their length.
5. Return the maximum of these substring lengths.

```
strings = [
    "BABABA125",  # 3
    "234CA4BACA",  # 2
    "BABACABACA56",  # 5
    "1BABA24CA",  # 2
    "NO_MATCH_TO_BE_FOUND",  # 0
]

def f4(string: str):
    string = string.replace("CA", "+")
    string = string.replace("BA", "+")
    string = "".join([(c if c == "+" else "-") for c in string])
    str_list = string.split("-")
    str_lengths = map(len, str_list)
    return max(str_lengths)

for s in strings:
    print(f4(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function `f2` that performs this operation.

1. `if not re.search('(BA|CA)', s): return 0`
   First check if the string actually contains any `BA` or `CA` (to prevent `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence` on step 3), and return 0 if there aren't any.
2. `matches = re.finditer(r'(?:CA|BA)+', s)`
   Find all consecutive sequences of `CA` or `BA`, using non-capturing groups to ensure `re.finditer` outputs only full matches instead of partial matches.
3. `res = max(matches, key=lambda m: len(m.group(0)))`
   Then, among the matches (`re.Match` objects), fetch the matched substring using `m.group(0)` and compare their lengths to find the longest one.
4. `return len(res.group(0))//2`
   Divide the length of the longest result by 2 to get the number of `BA` or `CA`s in this substring. Here we use floor division `//` to coerce the output into an `int`, since division would normally convert the answer to `float`.

```py
import re

strings = [
    "BABABA125",  # 3
    "234CA4BACA",  # 2
    "BABACABACA56",  # 5
    "1BABA24CA",  # 2
    "NO_MATCH_TO_BE_FOUND",  # 0
]

def f2(s: str):
    if not re.search('(BA|CA)', s): return 0
    matches = re.finditer(r'(?:CA|BA)+', s)
    res = max(matches, key=lambda m: len(m.group(0)))
    return len(res.group(0))//2

for s in strings:
    print(f2(s))
```

**UPDATE:** Thanks to @StevenRumbalski for providing a simpler version of the above answer. (I split it into multiple lines for readability)

```
def f3(s):
    if not re.search('(BA|CA)', s): return 0
    matches = re.findall(r'(?:CA|BA)+', s)
    max_length = max(map(len, matches))
    return max_length // 2
```

1. `if not re.search('(BA|CA)', s): return 0`
   Same as above
2. `matches = re.findall(r'(?:CA|BA)+', s)`
   Find all consecutive sequences of `CA` or `BA`, but each value in `matches` is a `str` instead of a `re.Match`, which is easier to handle.
3. `max_length = max(map(len, matches))`
   Map each matched substring to its length and find the maximum length  among them.
4. `return max_length // 2`
   Floor divide the length of the longest matching substring by the length of `BA`, `CA` to get the number of consecutive occurrences of `BA` or `CA` in this string.

Comment: Moving from `re.finditer()` to `re.findall()` does away with with groups awkwardness `max(map(len, re.findall(r'(?:CA|BA)+', s)), default=0) // 2`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Nice one! I was gonna use `findall` at first but was stumped when I saw the weird output (first time dealing with overlapping groups) so I just went with the first working solution. I'll add that to my answer in a bit, thanks!

Comment: @Fractalism I'm very grateful to you. But I really didn't think it'd be so difficult))) I'm not allowed to use libraries or regular expressions.